# Python: Dictionary formatting into list for graph

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I need some help formatting a dictionary into an output that can be used in a graph situation. Here is my code so far, all it does is sum the values in the dictionary and return them in a list:

```
def total(contestant):
    results = contestant[1]
    results.sort()
    del results[-1]
    return sum(results)

d = {"Alice": [1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 5], "Bob": [5, 2, 4, 1, 3, 5], "Clare": [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5], "Dennis": [2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3], "Eva": [2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3]}
# This is the dictionary that needs to be formatted
y = []
for item in d.items():
    y.append(total(item)) # total is a function that sums the integers
print(y)
```

This loop returns the following after summing the integers in D and sorting by lowest score first:

```
 [13, 15, 16, 18, 20]
```

However this doesn't really work for me, what I need is the following:

```
   data = [ ("Eva", 20), ("Bob", 22),("Dennis", 11), ( "Alice", 28),  ( "Clare, 28) ]
```

etc etc, numbers aren't correct but that's the format I need

I've tried to format the dictionary various ways but I've had no luck, if anyone could help me with this I would greatly appreciate it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to ***iterate*** over `key, value pairs` and then append both key and `sum of values` in `list` as `tuple`.

```
y = []
for key, item in d.iteritems():
    y.append((key,sum(item))) # total is a function that sums the integers
print(y)
```

**Gives Result** :

```
[('Clare', 18), ('Eva', 13), ('Bob', 20), ('Dennis', 16), ('Alice', 15)]
```

---

Can be done in simpler way using `list comprehension` and calculating total of values using built-in `sum` function:

```
>>> d = {"Alice": [1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 5],
...      "Bob": [5, 2, 4, 1, 3, 5],
...      "Clare": [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5],
...      "Dennis": [2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3],
...      "Eva": [2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3]}
>>> print  [(k, sum(v)) for k,v in d.iteritems()]
[('Clare', 18), ('Eva', 13), ('Bob', 20), ('Dennis', 16), ('Alice', 15)]
```

---

Get result sorted based on `Name`:

```
print sorted(y, key=lambda x: x[0])

[('Alice', 15), ('Bob', 20), ('Clare', 18), ('Dennis', 16), ('Eva', 13)]
```

Sorted result based on `sum of items`.

```
print sorted(y, key=lambda x: x[1])

[('Eva', 13), ('Alice', 15), ('Dennis', 16), ('Clare', 18), ('Bob', 20)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This will sort by scores as you want:

```
import operator
d = {"Alice": [1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 5], "Bob": [5, 2, 4, 1, 3, 5], "Clare": [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5], "Dennis": [2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3], "Eva": [2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3]}
print sorted(((k, sum(v)) for k,v in d.items()), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

#### Output:

```
[('Eva', 13), ('Alice', 15), ('Dennis', 16), ('Clare', 18), ('Bob', 20)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use lambda functions, map, sum and sorted:

```
d = {"Alice": [1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 5],
     "Bob": [5, 2, 4, 1, 3, 5],
     "Clare": [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5],
     "Dennis": [2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3],
     "Eva": [2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3]}

res = sorted(map(lambda k: (k, sum(d[k])), d), key=lambda pos: pos[1])
print res
```

This would give you:

```
[('Eva', 13), ('Alice', 15), ('Dennis', 16), ('Clare', 18), ('Bob', 20)]
```

**Explanation**:

- `map(lambda k: (k, sum(d[k])), d)` map will apply the lambda function in each element from the dict d, returning a list containing tuples in the form *(dict_key, sum_of_dict_key_values)*;
- `sorted` will sort the returned list using the value in the second (index 1) position of each tuple as the sorting key;

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit perplexed by this line

```
del results[-1]
```

in your code, because you're modifying destructively the dictionary content, but anyway it seems that your intention is to remove the higher score from each list before summation.

If I am correct in my interpretation of your post, this code should be ok for you

```
>>> d = {"Alice": [1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 5],
...      "Bob": [5, 2, 4, 1, 3, 5],
...      "Clare": [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5],
...      "Dennis": [2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3],
...      "Eva": [2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3]}
>>> 
>>> [(k,sum(sorted(v)[:-1])) for k, v in d.items()]
[('Clare', 13), ('Eva', 10), ('Bob', 15), ('Dennis', 13), ('Alice', 10)]
>>>
```

but it differs from yours because it has no side effects.

Forgot to mention, if you modify the `return` statement in your `total`

```
      return contestant[0], sum(results)
```

your code gives you already what you want...